# How do I make the progress of background tasks in queues?

Tags: python, php, node.js, laravel, web

I am studying the execution of background tasks via queues in php.
I use redis as a queue server

Here is the question...
How can I correctly make progress of background tasks in the queues?
for example...

1. converting video to another format
2. compressing a big image
3. import of products into the database from an external api

i assume the algorithm depends on the type of task...
case 3: if it is an import ... then you need to calculate the number of rows in the file, for example there are 300 lines,
we add 100 rows to the database
number of iterations = 300/100 = 3
3 iterations in total:
1-33%
2-66%
3-100%

case 2 "large image compression"...
How do I know the number of iterations here?
or at the moment of starting the vorker, increment the progress counter every second and
write/update the value in the "progress" field to the id_task and update the value to 100% when it finishes working

The general algorithm should probably be similar to this:

```
function progress(int $total)
{
    echo 'Starting task' . PHP_EOL;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $total; $i++) {
        $progress = 100 * $i / $total;
        echo $i . '-' . $progress . '%' . PHP_EOL;
        // some heavy task
        sleep(1);
    }
    $progress = 100;
    echo '$progress: ' . $progress . '%' . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Task completed' . PHP_EOL;
}

progress(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

With any queue, there is a process of pushing, and popping.

For example, with a playlist on a streaming service like Spotify, you will need to add a song to a queue in-order to play it, and then once its played, it will be removed from the queue. This is the pushing and popping process. If this didn't occur, you would have multiple songs playing at once.

So for your queue, you will need to check the progress of the task at hand. While you are checking the progress you can assess whether it is a worthy candidate to pop off the queue, or if it needs to stay in it.

Generally this is done via a **queue worker**.

A queue worker is responsible for **polling** the queue to check the status of each queue item, and popping it off if its completed. If completed, you may want to do something with the queue item before popping it off.

The other aspect to consider, is each task will be a seperate **asynchronous** process.

To allow each queue item to do an individual task, it will need to run independently of other items, and not rely on any other queue item.

Each queue item should responsibly update their own progress, or status - independent of the polling mechanism. The polling mechanism should simply check if it is completed, if it has reached the desired status, or if it has failed.

In terms of determining the size of the upload, it might be worth passing the file size as a parameter to the backend from the front end and picking it up on the back-end, and determining how much of it you have processed, and using the algorithm you have provided to determine the progress.